# Change cell's color in isCellEditable method of ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I need to change the cell's color if the cell is not editable.

I do not want to user renderer for this since i am doing lot of validations in isCellEditable method.

If I call isCellEditable method from renderer two times this method would be called and it would be a perforamance hit.

Any help is appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({

    store: store,

    id: 'editorgrid',
    columnLines : true,

    //more properties..

    cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        isCellEditable: function(colIndex, rowIndex) {
            if(colIndex == 1) {
                //before returning false I want to change the color of this cell i.e want to make it grayed out    
                return false;
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use a renderer for this? This is what renderers are made for. You can just as easily add a renderer to the column and in this renderer add a property to the meta object of the cell to change the color based on the editable state.

```
var myCellRenderer = function(value, metaData, record) {

   //metaData.css : String : A CSS class name to add to the cell's TD element.
   //metaData.attr : String : An html attribute definition string to apply to
   //                         the data container element within the table
   //                         cell (e.g. 'style="color:red;"').
   metaData.css = 'name-of-css-class';
   return value;

};
```

Straight from the ExtJS Grid faq at http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_FAQ_Grid

Comment: Hi Chris,Thanks for your reply .The issue here is i am doing lot of server side validations using AJAX in isCellEditable method and based on that i am returning values true or false to make a particualr cell editable or non editable.if it is non editable i.e returing false then it should be displayed in Gray color.Now, if i use a renderer i need to call iscelleditable method from within renderer method something like below as that is the only way to know whether a cell is editable or not and it in turn will call all the server side validation again and will affect the perfromance badly.Thanks

Comment: Are you really evaluating each single cell's editability through an ajax call or did i just understand that wrong? If so you'd probably be alot more effective by doing the evaluation in one run on the serverside when loading your store and still use a renderer that colors the cell based on the value in the store.